# nested div contents not showing up

Tags: html, css, css-position

I am playing youtube video on a page with a thumbnail coming from youtube and on tap of that i show a transparent Play image button.. and at bottom of the image i want to show title of the video like Latest Video, Featured video etc..

But for some reason label div container is not showing the text inside it, while it show the background color etc...

```
<div class="profile-icon"> <a href="#">
        <img alt="Latest Video" src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/GWGTPvOISSs/hqdefault.jpg" class="hp-video-thumbnail" title="Latest Video" >
        <div class="hp-playVideo">
             <img src="../../../images/something.png" alt="Play" class="imgPlayVideo" >
        </div>
        <div class="hp-video-label">Latest Video</div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/2Aa2X/2/

Demo has only one video

UPDATE:

I have other elements on page and if i use position:absolute; it moves the label/title out of it div wrapper example http://jsfiddle.net/2Aa2X/6/ same happens on my actual page..

I tried using span, label inside `hp-video-label` div container but it still moves out of it with position:absolute and if i don't mention it then text doesn't show. What is the reason for this i am not sure?

Comment: I wrap whole image & label inside anchor `<a href="#">...</a>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using wrong positioning techniques there, `position: absolute;` is best suited for this scenario... So make the child element `position: absolute;` and assign `position: relative;` to child element. To be true, your CSS is extremely dirty.

- You are using `margin` with elements positioned `absolute` which is not good, you need `margin` say when you need to center any element, or for some similar reason. If you use `position: absolute;` than use `top`, `right`, `bottom` and `left` properties to set the element correctly. Than use `margin` for a nudge.
- Than you are using `float` with `position: absolute;` element which is not at all required. So the approach is somewhat totally invalid.
- You are using `opacity` and am sure you won't like your text getting opaque as well, so use `rgba` instead. So `#008F3D` with an opacity of `0.5` equivalent `rgba` is `background-color: rgba(0, 143, 61, .5);`
- Last but not the least, nesting `div` inside an `a` tag is **invalid HTML**.

---

#### How would I do this?

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/YE9xN/)

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/YE9xN/1/) *(Added play button)*

```
.wrap {
    position: relative;
    margin: 20px;
    border: 3px solid #eee;
    display: inline-block;
}

.wrap img {
    display: block;
}

.wrap span {
    position: absolute;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,.5);
    bottom: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 180px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

---

Wrap the child elements using `a` tag

[**Demo 3**](http://jsfiddle.net/YE9xN/2/)

```
.wrap a {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks i just updated my question and it seems you have justified it with reason. let me check...

Comment: I solved it with bit of tweak, to make it work on my actual page. I used your code structure +1 for details & examples.

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker replace it with the markup I provided and glad you fixed it :)

Answer (score 0):

Use :

z-index: 999; or higher...  css property

if not showing
Add:

```
position:absolute;
```

for show buttons top of frame and etc...

Maybe help you...

Comment: Add position:absolute; to this class

Comment: This problem is occurred Lastweek... And i fix it by position and z-index;

Answer (score 0):

Hi please add `position:absolute` on your hp-video-label..

Fiddle :http://jsfiddle.net/nikhilvkd/2Aa2X/3/

css

```
.hp-video-label {
    background-color: rgba(0,143,61,0.5);
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 16px;
    height: 30px;
    opacity: 1;
    position: absolute;
    top: 98px;
    width:195px;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I have other elements on the page and changing the position:absolute move label out of its wrapper and moves it top of the page.. i made some changes to your html for example purpose http://jsfiddle.net/2Aa2X/6/

Answer (score 0):

Added `position:absolute` to your label, plus `text-align:center`

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2Aa2X/4/